# Is the rescue clause being called on descendent redefinition?

Tags: eiffel

Didn't find the answer on [this doc](https://www.eiffel.org/doc/eiffel/ET-_Design_by_Contract_%28tm%29%2C_Assertions_and_Exceptions), is the rescue clause called when redefining a feature?

### Class A

```
class A

feature -- 

    process
        do
            do_stuff
        rescue
            on_fail
        end
end -- class
```

### Class B

```
class B

inherit
    A
        redefine
            process
        end

feature -- 

    process
        do
            do_other_stuff -- do I have to call the rescue too?
        end
end -- class
```

Comment: @zx8754, why removing the language into title?

Comment: Language is in the tags, no need in the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rescue clauses are not inherited like contracts and should be supplied with every new feature body if needed.

Comment: For example the rescue in class A could use local variables which are not declared in class B.

Comment: So `rescue` clauses are parts of the implementation, and not part of the contract.

Comment: @U.Windl Right, `rescue` clauses are part of the implementation.